# How do I start analysing a spectrogram?

Tags: phonology

I was recently given a diagram of a spectrogram as part of an assignment. I'm not asking for answers, but rather, how do I start analysing one?

All the formants seem rather unclear to me, and as an image only, it seems near impossible to differentiate anything else besides vowels and consonants, even the distinctive nasals are hard to see. Any suggestions on how do I start learning and practicing to read one?

Comment: Don't you use a text in your class, like Ladefoged and Johnson 2014? See chapter 8, section "Interpreting spectrograms."

Comment: We do, Lagefoged's A Course in Phonetics in fact, but it hasn't been the most enlightening of all texts...

Answer (score 1):

Measure the durations of the vowels and consonants.  Look for voice bars to find the voiced consonants.  Look for narrowly spaced vertical striations due to vocal cord vibrations and possibly count them to estimate the fundamental frequency.  Trace out the centers of any formants you can see and try to identify the lowest two formants.  Note the slant of formants near consonant boundaries. ...

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend recording your own speech and getting familiar with how the different types of speech sounds that you produce look in a spectrogram. The more familiar you get with your own speech, and the more expectations you develop, the easier it will become to then start with a spectrogram and "reverse-engineer" it to determine what speech sounds it represents.

In terms of what to record, I suggest recording strategic minimal pairs/sets. For example, record *he*, *ha*, and *who*, which all start with the same consonant but contain different vowels, and then look at how their respective spectrograms differ. You could then switch it up and keep the vowel constant while varying the consonant.

It can also be enlightening to contrast two similar speech sounds by slowly gliding from one to the other--say from an [a] vowel to an [i] vowel, or from [s] to [ʃ] (of course this only works for speech sounds that can be elongated, like vowels and fricatives) and seeing how the spectrum "moves" over time.

Once you got comfortable and familiar with your own speech, it would be instructive to compare the same utterances produced by different speakers, so that you can get a sense of the types and range of variation you might expect for a given type of speech sound, as well as what types of visual cues are more robust across speakers.

Comment: I would add that you should practice making decent recordings. It's particularly hard to make sense of a spectrogram if you have a noisy recording  -- where the background noise looks like a fricative. In fact it might not be a bad idea to post the image, in case the problem is actually the recording quality.

Comment: Yes! +1 @user6726. Background white noise can look like frication, low frequency mechanical "hums" can look like voice bars, and sympathetic resonance in the recording space or by the recording equipment itself can mimic formants even after voicing has stopped. If the signal-to-noise ratio is too low, such issues can really degrade the readability of a spectrogram. Also make sure that the sampling rate is appropriate for speech, lest you cut off high frequency noise that sets sibilants apart from other fricatives.

Comment: I had an episode where /p t k/ had a clear voice bar -- which sounded like the previous vowel. Concrete walls.